# How to make multiple runtimes available inside docker? Like how Java and python altogether inside docker with required dependencies like asyncpg

Tags: java, python, linux, docker, asyncpg

I am working in a Java spring boot application, running as a docker container.

The main purose of this application was to execute python scripts.
So inside the docker container, I had to make available python environment. I added the python runtime with this code.
But seems this is very basic python verson and I can not make other important libraries available.

Like, I wanted to add 'asyncpg' library so that I can use connection pool.

But it is not letting me to add asyncpg library.

Below is the docker file.

Note: I have commented '#FROM python:3.6-alpine', if I make this open then java runtime will not be available which is 'FROM openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.8'

------- Docker file --------------

```
*FROM openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.8
#FROM python:3.6-alpine
## Install bash
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash
ENV APP_HOME /opt/app
# Create directory structure
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/logs
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/config
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/libs
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/scripts
# Add supporting script
ADD start.sh ${APP_HOME}/start.sh
RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/start.sh
ADD wait-for-it.sh ${APP_HOME}/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/wait-for-it.sh
ADD load-ext-packages.sh ${APP_HOME}/load-ext-packages.sh
RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/load-ext-packages.sh
## Add Spring Boot runnable jar
ADD *.jar ${APP_HOME}/
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/logs" ]
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/config" ]
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/libs" ]
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/scripts" ]
    
# Install Python
RUN apk add build-base 
RUN apk add --update gcc
RUN apk --update add gcc build-base freetype-dev libpng-dev openblas-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 python3-dev libevent-dev && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    pip3 install wheel && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir asyncpg && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
    if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
    rm -r /root/.cache
CMD ["./start.sh"]*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got one solution .. that at the first line of the docker file, I will first decleare the 'FROM alpine:3.7', and then inside the docker file I will keep adding the required runtimes and the dependent libraries accordingly. This way we can add mutiple runtimes.

Below the working docker compose where I have commented out both the lines for openjdk and python runtime and added FROM alpine:3.7:
Also some trick to add asyncpg library to the python runtime. This way I can now add any dependencies.
I can now work on asyncpg.

-------- Docker file ----------------

```
*#FROM openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.8
#FROM python:3.6-alpine
FROM alpine:3.7
## Install bash
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash
ENV APP_HOME /opt/app
# Create directory structure
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/logs
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/config
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/libs
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}/scripts
# Add supporting script
ADD start.sh ${APP_HOME}/start.sh
RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/start.sh
ADD wait-for-it.sh ${APP_HOME}/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/wait-for-it.sh
ADD load-ext-packages.sh ${APP_HOME}/load-ext-packages.sh
RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/load-ext-packages.sh
## Add Spring Boot runnable jar
ADD *.jar ${APP_HOME}/
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/logs" ]
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/config" ]
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/libs" ]
VOLUME [ "${APP_HOME}/scripts" ]
    
RUN apk add build-base --no-cache python3 python3-dev && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir asyncpg && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
    if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
    rm -r /root/.cache
RUN apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies unzip \
&& apk add --no-cache curl \
&& apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre
CMD ["./start.sh"]*
```